# Mockito Argument Captors and Reference Variable

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following bit of code that some long-departed developer wrote:

```
        Document doc = new Document();
        dao.load(doc, documentId);
```

This bit of code is very close to untestable, as I don't know how to mock out the result.

Is it possible to use an ArgumentCaptor to mock the result of the dao to provide a given value for the `doc` value for a given `documentId`? I'd prefer NOT to change the dao call at this time (if possible).

Edit: I was requested to flesh out the above example. This is a simplified version of it:

```
@Controller
public class DocumentController {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentDAO dao;

    public Document getDocument(int documentId) throws Exception {

       // ensure documentId is valid

       // ensure user has access to documentId

        Document doc = new Document();
        int rc = dao.load(doc, documentId);

        // if rc is bad throw an Exception

        return doc;
    }
```

I understand it would make MUCH more sense to return the Document from the `load()` method, unfortunately the original developer was trying to do two things at once.

I'm trying to NOT introduce new methods if possible. I just need to know if I'm using Mockito to mock a `DocumentDAO` instance, can I adjust an input in the manner the above method does.

Comment: What are you testing? (What class does this occur in?) Where does `dao` come from—a method argument, a field, or something else? Are you allowed to introduce other testing seams, such as making a for-testing method overload that accepts `dao` from the test?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question, but maybe you are looking for something of the sort:

```
public class DocumentControllerTest {

@Mock
private DocumentDAO dao;

@InjectMocks
private DocumentController controller;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void simpleTest() {
    Document inputDoc = ...
    int yourid = ...
    Mockito.when(dao.load(inputDoc,yourid)).thenReturn(whateveryouwanttoreturn);
    Document d = controller.getDocument(inputDoc,yourid);

    //check if dao method was called with the expected input
    Mockito.verify(dao, Mockito.times(1)).load(inputDoc,yourid);

    // do yur asserts
    Assert.assertNotNull("Doc shouldn't be null", d);
    Assert.assertEquals("Doc shoud be the expected one.", inputDoc, d);
}
```

}